# Rules for Block Diagram Reduction, how to do this

Tags: diagram

I have to solve, to reduce this block diagram:
[image]
But I don't know how to do it, I know somthing about the rules to do it, but its to basical, this complex. I tryied to do this :
[image]
And now?

Comment: Write the signal expressions on each line until you get the output in terms of the input and the gains. Then see how you can simplify it and redraw.

Comment: It's not that complex. Don't be a baby. You've made a good start. repeat what you did for A/B with C/D and there's another step down the path.

Comment: But C/D has the sum,A/B had just the node. Right?..I dont know how to proced in this case..can you Make me an answer Please?

Comment: @Eugene Sh. What did you Mean?

Comment: Are you asking for a list of rules (can be found in each good book on control systems)? Or are you asking WHICH of this rules could be recommended? (There is always a number of different approaches).

Comment: @LvW i Want to know the rules for this exercises on C/D

Comment: As I have mentioned - a list of rules is available in control sysytem books/articles.